# Show $\log \prod_p\frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}=\sum_p\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{np^{ns}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, number-theory

I'm trying to show:

> $$\log \prod_p\frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}=\sum_p\sum_{n=1}^\infty
>  \frac{1}{np^{ns}}$$

Using the properties of the logarithm I get:

$$\log \prod_p\frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}=\sum_p\log\frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}=\sum_p(\log 1-\log (1-p^{-s}))=$$
$$=-\sum_p \log(1-p^{-s})=-\sum_p \log\bigg(\frac{p^s-1}{p^s}\bigg)$$

The log can be expanded more, but it seems to get me farther from the result.

I realize that the sum over $n$ comes from a geometric sum, but I don't see where to get it from, or how to get rid of the logarithm.

Thanks in advance for any help or tips!

Comment: Hint: try the Taylor series for $\log(1-x)$ and let $x=p^{-s}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Progress you made:
$$\log\prod_p \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}=-\sum_p\log(1-p^{-s})$$

Taylor series:
$$\log(1-x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{-x^n}{n}$$

Plug and chug:
$$\log(1-p^{-s})=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{-p^{-sn}}{n}$$

$$\log\prod_p \frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}=-\sum_p\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{-p^{-sn}}{n}=\sum_p\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{np^{sn}}$$